# Bootsrap autohidingnavbar not works smooth on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap autohiding navbar works jumping when we scrolls on internet explorer browser 
it is not smooth. please give a solution 
link is http://www.usawebdept.com/designprojects/Almarelo/demo1/buyer-Dashboard.html

Answer (score 0):

I found an article exactly on your issue posted.

http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/

Also listed in the comments are some other suggestions if you don't like the suggested answer, such as:

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:1px
}
```